MassTransit unit testing endpoint with no response
I have a fairly straightforward example and want to unit test an endpoint that has not response. I have seen examples of using this and it works as expected.
        var harness = new InMemoryTestHarness();
        harness.Consumer<FooBarConsumer>();
        
        await harness.Start();
        await harness.InputQueueSendEndpoint.Send<FooCommand>(new FooCommand());
        
        Assert.IsTrue(await harness.Consumed.Any<FooCommand>());


However, I would like to do this with ServiceProvider so that I can setup and mock dependencies. This is what I have so far
        await using var provider = new ServiceCollection()
            .AddMassTransitTestHarness(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.UsingInMemory((ctx, mem) =>
                {
                    mem.ConfigureEndpoints(ctx);
                });
                cfg.AddConsumer<FooBarConsumer>();
            })
            .BuildServiceProvider(true);

If I try doing the following I get an error stating this hasn't been registered.
var harness = provider.GetRequiredService<InMemoryTestHarness>();

The example states to do this instead
var harness = provider.GetRequiredService<ITestHarness>();

However by doing this I don't get access to InputQueueSendEndpoint. It forces me down the route of request and response but there is no output for this endpoint.
        var client = harness.GetRequestClient<FooCommand>();
        await client.GetResponse<FooBar>(new FooCommand());


I guess question is, is it possible to test a consumer who receives a command only with no output using InMemoryTestHarness but also setup its dependencies?

For testing a consumer, would simply calling the appropriate .Consume method suffice? You can mock the relevant ConsumeContext<T>.

I don't understand what you mean by that.. if I have constructor depedencies how would I mock them?

I like using Moq and AutoMocker. You can ask automocker to create an instance of your consumer class for you, and it will construct the appropriate mocks that its constructor needs. If you need any of those mocks to behave in a certain way, then it's simple enough to configure that, too.

You're suggesting to create the instance of the consumer directly bypassing the need of the TestHarness?

Yes. Personally I skip the message bus in all unit tests. I can test that a publisher attempted to publish a message. I can test that a consumer properly consumes messages. Once we get to the point of integration tests, we either test over LocalStack (which only really works for AWS), or use the actual configured bus.

The testing documentation shows how to configure and start the test harness. If you're only testing a consumer without a response, just use harness.Bus.Publish().
If you insist on using Send, call harness.GetConsumerEndpoint<T> and then call Send on it.
Also, using mocks/etc. and calling Consume directly is a really bad approach to unit testing consumers. I highly discourage it (@AndyG).

Please elaborate on why directly calling consume is a bad unit testing approach
